# Getting a 70002 error when trying to register a secondary customer profile (ISV)

Tags: twilio-api

## I'm attempting to complete step 1.7 here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/a2p-10dlc/onboarding-isv-api#17-assign-end-users-supporting-document-and-primary-customer-profile-to-the-empty-secondary-customer-profile-that-you-created

I am able to add authorized_representative_1, customer_profile_business_information, and primary_customer_profile successfully to the secondary customer profile, but when trying to add the address, I receive the following error:

"body": "{"code": 70002, "message": "Attempting to add invalid Object Type to Bundle", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/70002", "status": 400}"

I have verified that the correct address sid is being passed (pulled the id from within my twilio account) and that the address looks properly formed within the twilio console.